# how to create the multiple values with same key in array in php

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array with multiple key.

**Array 1**

```
$age = array("Peter"=>"35", "Ben"=>"37", "Joe"=>"43");
```

**Output**

```
Array ( [Peter] => 35 [Ben] => 37 [Joe] => 43 )
```

**Expected Output**

```
$age = array("value"=>"35", "value"=>"37", "value"=>"43");
Array ( [value] => 35 [value] => 37 [value] => 43 )
```

Answer (score 1):

**You can't**

Indeed, array keys must be unique. Otherwise, what should the program output when you try to access value ?

**But ...**

If you need to store a list of value for one key, you can use array of arrays.

```
$array = array("value" => array());
array_push($array["value"], 35, 40, 53);
print_r($array)
```

And the output will be:

```
Array
(
    [value] => Array
        (
            [0] => 35
            [1] => 40
            [2] => 53
        )

)
```

Answer (score 1):

Only way is to turn this array into 2D array:

```
$age = array(
    array("value" => "35"),
    array("value" => "37"),
    array("value" => "43")
);

-- Output --
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [value] => 35
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [value] => 37
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [value] => 43
        )

)

-- Usage -- 
$age[0]['value'];
$age[1]['value'];
$age[2]['value'];
```

But it completely depends if `$age` array is in our control and can be changed.

Answer (score 0):

### You can't

Array keys must be unique.

http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php

> If multiple elements in the array declaration use the same key, only the last one will be used as all others are overwritten.

Comment: yup i know. no way to get this output ?

Comment: No there is no way to get this output.

Comment: No idea why this is down voted, it's right, you cannot have identical array keys in the same level.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, array key should be unique. So, whatever you are asking it's not possible. Can you tell us what's requirements? So that, people can suggest any alternate solution.

Answer (score 0):

This cannot be possible with native php arrays. What you need is a multimap, and you can find several implementations of it on github.
For example: [link](https://github.com/abelperez/php-commons/blob/master/src/mindplex/commons/collections/Multimap.php)

EDIT: the link above is an interface. you need to include also [link2](https://github.com/abelperez/php-commons/blob/master/src/mindplex/commons/collections/ArrayMultimap.php)